# Can a linear system of equations be solved if it has all zeros in the column matrix on the right hand side of the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have an awkward linear system of equations that I am trying solve. But it has a column matrix containing only $0$s on the right hand side. I want to know if this type of system can even be solved. I tried constructing a simpler set of equations to see if it is possible (I assumed $x=1, y=2, z=3$ and made equations with these values in mind). The simpler system of equations:

$-2x + y = 0,$

$3y -2z = 0,$

$3x - z = 0 $

But I cannot think of way that can be used to solve even this simple system. Conventional way of inversing the co-efficient matrix and then multiplying it with the column matrix on the right hand side yields another column matrix containing only 0 s. Please tell me if these systems can even be solved, and if so, how.

Comment: I think what you refer to is a *homogenous* system of linear equations. In that case, $x=y=z=\ldots=0$ is always a solution - but there may well be more. In your example, $2\cdot(3x-z)+3\cdot(-2x+y)=3y-2z$, hence the equations are not independent - you can simply drop one and then there will be infinitely many solutions. The standard methods work also in this case

Comment: The system has infinite number of solutions. You can find any solution from just two equations and they will work for the third. For example, you can plug in $x=0$ in the first equation. You will get $x=y=z=0$ I suspect this happens because you can derive the third equation from the first 2. Its just a matter of manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Hagen von Eitzen is a perfect answer.

In your case, the system is a system of homogeneous equations.

Such systems always have the zero vector as a solution. In addition it may have other solutions. This can be found by either inspection by calculating the determinant.

Calculating the determinant:
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}-2&1&0\\ \:0&3&-2\\ \:3&0&-1\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

The determinant "determines" whether the system has a unique solution.This occurs precisely if the determinant is non-zero.

So in your case, the system has a trivial solution $x=0$,$y=0$,$z=0$ in addition to infinitely number of solutions. To find the general form of those infinite solutions, you can let $z=Constant$, so let $$z=k$$.

Now use this value in equation (2) to get:

$$y=\frac{2k}{3}$$

Now use this value for $y$ in equation (1) to determine the value of $x$:

$$-2x+ \frac{2k}{3}=0$$

This leads to:

$$x=\frac{k}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can represent the system in matrix form $Ax=0$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}-2& 1 &0 \\0&3&-2\\3&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Recall that we can view the above matrix multiplication as a combination of the columns of matrix $A$ (i.e. $x_1\cdot \vec{a_1} + \dots + x_3\cdot \vec{a_3}$). A useful high-level interpretation of the question of whether we are going to be able to find a non-trivial solution: **is there some linear combination of the columns of $A$ that give the zero vector?**

The answer to the above is not immediately obvious in this case. So along with many other methods for determining the answer to this (such as computing the determinant of $A$), you could perform **Gaussian Elimination** on the matrix to shed light on the *nullspace* (the subspace containing all solutions $x$ to our $Ax=0$). For more on this, see Strang: Introduction to Linear Algebra; Section 3.2)